# MarkLogic - slowness in xdmp:document-filter

Tags: marklogic

Using ML version '8.0-8'

`xdmp:document-filter()` is very slow.
For 2 MB file, it's taking 2.0 seconds to filter the content.

Notes:

- PDF doc contains mostly text data
- Second parameter to the function is `()`

Please help me in, is there anything I need to know to make it work faster or is there any other API which is faster?

**Update:**

I have one ML REST API. Which will take `1 XML` and `1 PDF` in binary.

Then it will extract the content from the PDF using `xdmp:document-filter()` and insert it into the XML using `mem` functions.

Then both the XML and PDF will be inserted into DB.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11845977/14419

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to improve xdmp:document-filter() performance in Marklogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845977/how-to-improve-xdmpdocument-filter-performance-in-marklogic)

Comment: I can't use information studio. In my case, there is ML API which will take 1 xml & 1 pdf. It will extract the content from pdf and put it in the xml, then insert the xml & pdf into the db. To get the content from pdf I am using `xdmp:document-filter`. In this scenario what I can do to make it faster?

Comment: @MadsHansen I have updated the question, Please have a look.

Comment: @wst I have updated the question, Please have a look

Comment: Please respond.

Answer (score 1):

`xdmp:document-filter()` speed depends on the document size because it returns metadata and text in `XHTML` format.

You may use CPF functionality of MarkLogic which will do these things at back end.

Comment: For 2 MB pdf it's taking 2 seconds. Is this the expected behaviour? Note :  Pdf contains text data only.

Comment: Yes, it is. It is also converting it into XHTML.

Comment: Okay, Thanks Navin.